# Doubt about the module of coinvariants

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Suppose that $G$ is group, $R$ is a ring (commutative, associative with $1\neq0$) and $M$ is a left $RG-$módulo such that $M$ is free as a left $R-$module. Is it true that the module of coinvariants $M_{G}$ is free? $$M_{G}:=M/Q,$$ where $Q$ is the submodule generated by the elements $gm-m$ for all $g\in G$ and $m\in M$.

Comment: My guess would be no, and that one should be able to find a counter example by considering a ring $R$ and a suitable non-trivial automorphism (and letting $G$ be generated by this automorphism), then $R_G$ will probably be a proper non-trivial quotient of the rank $1$ $R$-module.

Comment: Indeed, taking $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and $G = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ acting by $n\mapsto -n$ works.

Comment: Of course, thanks. Do you know if under certain circumstance this holds?

Comment: The module of coinvariants is not $M/M^G$, but the module defined by the formula used in the question. In this case, what is called $Q$ there is $2\mathbb{Z}$ since  $gm-m = -2m$, so $M_G = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. In general, the module of coinvariants is the largest quotient on which $G$ acts trivially, just as the module of invariants is the largest submodule on which $G$ acts trivially.